# Change values in a JSON file C#

Tags: c#, json, object

I have this code. How do I change the values of the JSON objects in code.

```json
"externalReference": "Integrator Reference",
  "proposalType": "Private Individual",
  "dealer": {
    "dealerID": 9344
  },
  "financeDetails": {
    "type": "HP",
    "cashDeposit": 111,
    "settlement": 11,
    "partExchange": 22,
    "term": 72,
    "apr": 12.9,
    "loanamount": 0.0,
    "distanceSelling": true,
    "vehicleAsset": {
      "type": "Used",
      "class": "Car",
      "source": "UK",
      "purpose": "Social",
      "vrm": "string",
      "dateOfRegistration": "16-10-2020",
      "manufacturer": "string",
      "model": "string",
      "derivative": "string",
      "capCode": "ALGU21S164SDTA",
      "CurrentMileage": 25000,
      "vatRate": 20,
      "netValue": 5000
    },
    "additionalAssets": [
      {
        "type": "MOT",
        "netValue": 250,
        "vatRate": 20,
        "description": "string"
      },
      {
        "type": "BCI_VAT",
        "netValue": 350,
        "vatRate": 5,
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I have this so far;

```cs
public static void CallRequest(string fieldName, string enteredFieldValue)
{
    string sendProposalRequestSuccess = File.ReadAllText(sendProposalUnityJSONFile);
    dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sendProposalRequestSuccess);
    jsonObj[fieldName] = enteredFieldValue;
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(sendProposalUnityJSONFile, output);
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: Indeed, please give more information about what happens with your current code (ideally as a [mcve] we can run ourselves). It's hard to help solve a problem when we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I can see that a  fieldName can cause a problem in your code. Please show us what fieldName you were trying to change.

Comment: Your issue might come from the case sensitiveness of the properties you are trying to access, sometimes you have properties with camel case some with pascal case, for example CurrentMileage and capCode and if you try to access properties from another objet we don't know how you try to access it, you should provide more information

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JObject` which has a method to parse json text you read from file to json objects. You can then access property using keys depending on the depth of the property.

**1) JObject Parsing and Modification**

```csharp
string sendProposalRequestSuccess = File.ReadAllText("myjson.json");
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(sendProposalRequestSuccess);

jsonObj["proposalType"] = "Private Company";
jsonObj["financeDetails"]["cashDeposit"] = 213;

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("myjson2.json", output);
```

**Demo Example:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DZA5BI

---

**2) Json to C# Classes:**

Another approach is convert `json` to `C#` classes using this helpful [online tool](https://json2csharp.com/). You can then deserialize json object to main class `MyJson`. This way you can access each property field and modify at your will then save json back to file.

This is pretty useful if you want to save to database or show in a table and several other applications.

```csharp
public class MyJson
{
    public string externalReference { get; set; }
    public string proposalType { get; set; }
    public Dealer dealer { get; set; }
    public FinanceDetails financeDetails { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalAsset
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int netValue { get; set; }
    public int vatRate { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Dealer
{
    public int dealerID { get; set; }
}

public class FinanceDetails
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int cashDeposit { get; set; }
    public int settlement { get; set; }
    public int partExchange { get; set; }
    public int term { get; set; }
    public double apr { get; set; }
    public double loanamount { get; set; }
    public bool distanceSelling { get; set; }
    public VehicleAsset vehicleAsset { get; set; }
    public List<AdditionalAsset> additionalAssets { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleAsset
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string @class { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string purpose { get; set; }
    public string vrm { get; set; }
    public string dateOfRegistration { get; set; }
    public string manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string derivative { get; set; }
    public string capCode { get; set; }
    public int CurrentMileage { get; set; }
    public int vatRate { get; set; }
    public int netValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```csharp
string sendProposalRequestSuccess = File.ReadAllText("myjson.json");
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJson>(sendProposalRequestSuccess);

jsonObj.financeDetails.cashDeposit = 231;

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("myjson2.json", output);
```

**Output:**

[image: Output of json property modification]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I tried this and it is not changing it?
This is my method

public static void CallRequest()
        {
            string sendProposalRequestSuccess = File.ReadAllText(sendProposalUnityJSONFile);
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendProposalRequest>(sendProposalRequestSuccess);
            jsonObj.financeDetails.CashDeposit = 231;
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(sendProposalUnityJSONFile, output);
        }
And I have correctly set up the myJson file

Comment: @kieranm007 Include all the classes in your program and deserialize the json object using the root class type which is `MyJson`

Comment: Creating classes to represent all of this feels quite brittle and cumbersome when all that's needed is a change to a single property. If a field is added to the JSON, it would be needed to be added to the class or you'd either silently lose information or crash... whereas the original approach maintains the data.

Comment: @JonSkeet The title of the question is how to change values in a json not a single property. In my example I show to change a single property just to show how it can be done. Furthermore, there are more applications to deserialize to a class for example to save to database, or to show in a table and several others.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons you *might* want to deserialize to a class, yes - but also reasons *not* to want to do so, as I've outlined. Your answer doesn't currently contain any of the downsides of this approach, which I think are pretty significant in terms of both the amount of code *and* the fragility of this solution. Unfortunately the question doesn't give enough information to provide an answer to why the OP's current approach doesn't work, but I see no reason to abandon it just yet.

Comment: @kieranm007 I have updated my answer with a simple better solution

Comment: @JonSkeet I have update my answer to include a simpler solution. Let me know if it is alright. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I don't see how  a string fieldName is going to work in your solution.And you don't need to repeat all OP code, just to change one line. It makes your code very messy.

Comment: @Serge Regarding string fieldName, Can you clarify more and give an example. I gave two solution, the 2nd solution i understand is a bit too much, therefore, it is extra.

Comment: I am not an OP . You should ask OP some clarification before posting your code.